# Do sparse graphs contain regular pairs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

An easy corollary of the Szemerédi Regularity Lemma is that dense graphs contain linear sized $\varepsilon$-regular bipartite subgraphs whose density is similar to that of the parent graph. As noted by Tim Gowers in (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291467/is-there-a-weak-strong-regularity-lemma) there are easier ways of seeing this, with better bounds.

I'm wondering if a meaningful statement with the above flavor holds for sparse graphs, of density $\Omega(n^{-1/t})$. That is, graphs which are dense enough to necessarily contain $K_{t,t}$ subgraphs.

What I'm looking for exactly is a subgraph $(A,B)$ that satisfies $|A|=|B|=k$, $e(A,B)=\Omega(k^{2-1/t})$, and further, $(A,B)$ is $\varepsilon$-regular, in the sense that any subgraph $(A', B')$ with $\varepsilon k$ vertices on each side satisfies $e(A,B)=\Omega(k^{2-1/t})$. Note that this is a lot weaker than the usual notion of $\varepsilon$-regularity in that we allow that the density of a subgraph to be off by a constant factor from the density of the the parent graph, all that we insist on is that they are of the same order of magnitude.

I'm okay with aiming for a sub-linear sized regular pair (i.e. take $k=o(n)$) as the graph itself could be almost entirely filled with isolated vertices, except for a small clique, as Misha says. I would expect one could take $k$ polynomial in $n$, but I'm interested in any range where $k$ grows with $n$.

I'm also okay with assuming that the graph is $K_{10t, 10t}$-free (say), although I cannot tell if there is an easy construction that shows the necessity of such an assumption.

From what I can tell, the sparse versions of Regularity Lemma do not say anything immediately meaningful here, as they do not forbid all edges of the sparse graph being between non-regular pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without ruling out big complete bipartite graphs, one counterexample is the following sparse graph: a complete graph on about $n^{1-1/(2t)}$ vertices, together with enough isolated vertices to bring the total to $n$.

There are plenty of ways to pick a bipartite subgraph with $\epsilon n$ vertices in each part that has the correct density. However, all of these will include a linear number of isolated vertices in each part, so all of them will have linear-sized subgraphs with $0$ edges, and the thing you want cannot hold.

Comment: Right, of course, the hypothesis is obviously necessary in retrospect. Any intuition for when big complete graphs are disallowed?

Comment: I would even be interested if subgraphs existed on potentially sub-linearly many vertices, changing the density requirement for the subgraph to being dense enough to contain a $K_{t,t}$ by KST Theorem, and the same holding for linear sized subgraphs of that subgraph. Your counterexample doesn't rule out this possibility, as one could take the clique to be the subgraph.

Comment: I haven't thought this through and I'm not likely to get the chance, but in general: if we only consider $H$-free graphs, but there is an $H$-free graph on $o(n)$ vertices with $\Theta(n^{2-1/t})$ edges, then the same construction still works, using that $o(n)$-vertex graph in place of the clique. Off the top of my head I don't remember the KST bound that says if $H = K_{t,t}$ allows for this.

Comment: If you are on $n'=o(n)$ vertices but you have $\Omega(n^{2 -1/t})$ edges, this means that your density is of the form $n'^{-1/t + \varepsilon}$, which means that you will contain a $K_{t,t}$ (in fact something slightly larger) by the KST theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 1.1 here answers (a very close approximation of) my question. https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v9i1r1

In the regime where $1/t \ll \varepsilon$, in a graph with density $\Omega(n^{-1/t})$, we may find a subgraph $(A,B)$ with $k$ vertices on each part, where $k\geq n^{1-\gamma}$, and $(A,B)$ is $\varepsilon$-regular, and has density $\Omega(n^{-1/t})$.

The first caveat is that we need $1/t \ll \varepsilon$ to apply this theorem so that $\gamma$ is small. The second is that the density of $(A,B)$ is not $\Omega(k^{-1/t})$, but $\Omega(n^{-1/t})$, hence polynomially smaller than what I asked for. Still, this is a lot of  useful information.